# How do you do this?

Tags: android, listview

This is what I defined as my listview array.

```
private String lv_arr[] = {"number1", "number2", "number3", "number4"};
```

How can I change those to be linked to `number1.java`, `number2.java`, `number3.java` and `number4.java`?

[Edited]

Link : http://pastebin.com/BH8N4dKb

[Edited]
http://pastebin.com/GjrBj2m5

now i have no error, but it still does not have anything else.

Comment: what do you mean by "number#.java" ?

Comment: By the way, "How do you do this?" is not a very useful question title. Try editing it to something more descriptive. I'd do it myself but I don't really understand the question...

Comment: In your code at http://pastebin.com/BH8N4dKb, remove ListView lv = getListView();  and directly use your ListView lv1 to set adapter on it. You can do like, lv1.setAdapter(adapter); and one more thing, you have no items in your array named lv_arr[].

Comment: adapter in this case refers to? another variable ?

Comment: anyone? im really stuck 
http://pastebin.com/GjrBj2m5

Comment: You'll get stuck very often if you don't start to learn to debug your code yourself.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean hey, just sent you a mail! I have to leave now but check it out! See you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, Categories));
    ListView lv = getListView();      
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

              switch (position){
              case 0: Intent animalsGridViewIntent = new Intent(ListOfAppGallery.this,N1.class);     
                      ListOfAppGallery.this.startActivity(animalsGridViewIntent);
                      break;
              case 1: Intent calenderGridViewIntent = new Intent(ListOfAppGallery.this,N2.class);     
                      ListOfAppGallery.this.startActivity(calenderGridViewIntent);
                      break;
              case 2: Intent carsGridViewIntent = new Intent(ListOfAppGallery.this,N3.class);     
                      ListOfAppGallery.this.startActivity(carsGridViewIntent);
                      break;
              case 3: Intent creativeGridViewIntent = new Intent(ListOfAppGallery.this,N4.class);     
                      ListOfAppGallery.this.startActivity(creativeGridViewIntent);
                      break;

          }
      }
   });    
}
```

Comment: where do i place this code under?

Comment: What kind of an answer is this? Please at least describe the code and why or how it can solve the OPs question.

Comment: polam, you wanna explain on how it works?

Comment: when u click on item 1 u will get n1 activity , it will work depending on position of items.

Comment: what about the last few lines?

Comment: okay, seen, i did the changes above

Comment: I have 2 errors, i just edited my top post, pls check for me. tyvm

Comment: that is only for the string array declaration if u r using string from  xml this is not required. ignore that.

Comment: now i dont see anything except my search bar

Comment: problam with u r array.or may be in manifest declare all activities in manifest.

Comment: i got it alr, but i got another error.

Comment: now that i can see them inside, but my activites, if i type 4 in search, then number 4 comes up, then it will come up with number 1's activity instead of number 4's

Comment: its like the activity for number 1 is locked to the first option of the listview

Comment: its not an error, its the misconcept

Comment: therefore, from there, my first option, no matter what i type, will only be my first activity., yet not the activity that i typed in

Comment: it will start from 0 (zero) that is positions if u click on first item it will give the activity placed in the case 0 :

Comment: i want the activity place in other position

Comment: its like, now my activity is the third, and i search for it, it becomes first position right? then how do i get it as the third activity instead of getting it as the first

Comment: huh? i dont get it? arrange array list? then it will have the same problem...

Comment: i want to be able to search and link to the activity that is fixed on the item i am searching for, not the activity i fixed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Catch on your listview :
 `listView.setOnItemOnClickListener()` and check for the check for the case to start a new activity:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) {
                                        Intent intent;
                    switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NumberOne.java)
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NumberTwo.java);
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NumberThree.java);
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NumberFour.java);
                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

});